# Matplotlib make color map have no transparency

Tags: matplotlib

```
def visualize(goal_x, goal_y, goal_z, epoch_arr):
    # %% Create Color Map
    colormap = plt.get_cmap("binary")
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(epoch_arr), vmax=max(epoch_arr))

    # %% 3D Plot
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax3D = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax3D.set_facecolor('xkcd:salmon')

    ax3D.scatter(goal_x, goal_y, goal_z, s=100, c=colormap(norm(epoch_arr.values)), marker='o')

    plt.show()
```

The above code produces the following picture:
[image]

However, as you can see there is a point in the right side that is clearly still not 100% opaque. You can see the grid lines through the point. How do I make the scatter plot points 100% opaque, no transparency?

Answer (score 1):

Some tricks will help. Here I plot all the markers in white first, then plot again on top using the intended color.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# make-up some data
goal_x = list(range(10))
goal_y = list(range(10))
goal_z = list(range(10))
epoch_arr = np.linspace(0,1,10)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax3D = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax3D.set_facecolor('xkcd:salmon')

# First plot: all markers are in white color
ax3D.scatter(goal_x, goal_y, goal_z, s=500, c='w', marker='o', alpha=1.0, zorder=10)

colormap = plt.get_cmap("binary")
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(epoch_arr), vmax=max(epoch_arr))
#ax3D.scatter(goal_x, goal_y, goal_z, s=100, c=colormap(norm(epoch_arr.values)), marker='o')

# Second plot: use intended colormap
ax3D.scatter(goal_x, goal_y, goal_z, s=500, c='b', marker='o', zorder=11)

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting `alpha=1` should be enough.

```
ax3D.scatter(..., alpha=1)
```

Alternatively set `depthshade=False`

```
ax3D.scatter(..., depthshade=False)
```

The result will be the same in both cases.

[image]